# Loading Spinner Gif not showing during ajax request

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to get a loading spinner to show whilst the ajax is happening however i dont see any output.
I can confirm the spinner is there because if i remove the `style="display: none;"` it displays when the page loads. However i want it to show during the request, which it is not doing. Where am i going wrong?

Also the request does get returned as successufull too.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="button" class="submit" id="submit">Submittt</button>
</form>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" style="display: none;" />
<div class="modal" name="modal" id="modal"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click", ".submit", function () {

      alert(1)

      $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#modal').show();
      }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#modal').hide();
      });

      $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#modal').show();
      }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#modal').hide();
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{url_for('test_ajax')}}",
        data: {
        },
        success: function (response) {
          alert("success")
        },
      });


    });

  });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You're showing the modal - `$('#modal').show();`, not the loader..

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('img').css({'display':'block'});
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('img').css({'display':'none'});
});
```

Since you need to update the property of img tag & your model dont have anything to show.

Comment: that works thanks a lot, but i want it to block the entire screen and display in the middle. Would that be possible?